# Listen to UDP data on local port with netcat

Tags: udp, netcat, listener

`netcat -ul -p2115` fails with a usage statement.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 97, accepted):

To quote the [`nc` man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/nc):

> `-l` Used to specify that nc should listen for an incoming connection rather than initiate a connection to a remote host.  It is an error to use this option in conjunction with the -p, -s, or -z options.  Additionally, any timeouts specified with the -w option are ignored.

The key here is that `-p` cannot be combined with the `-l` flag.  When using the `-l` flag, any ports specified in the positional arguments are used.  So instead, you could use the following:

```
netcat -ul 2115
```

Answer (score 31):

`-p` is wrong. This will work on RedHat- and Debian-based distros:

```
nc -u -l 2115
```

Answer (score 12):

For some reason, Andrew's solution didn't work for me. With further research, I learned that we need to add -p flag when working locally. So the following command worked for me.

```
 nc -ulp 2115
```

Comment: Probably becuase there's two separate and subtly incompatible implementations of netcat in common use.

Comment: I also had this problem on debian stretch. The version of netcat installed was `1.10-41`.